# Was schreibt man, um einen Witz anzudeuten, ohne Emoticons zu nutzen?

Tags: writing, sociolinguistics

Scherzen ist sprachabhängig. Deswegen stelle ich diese Frage hier, und nicht auf der Seite zu [Linguistik](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Nehmen wir an, dass man einen Brief – oder eine normale E-Mail  – schreiben will. Da möchte man nun einen Witz machen, ohne dies explizit zu erwähnen. Das heißt, der Witz muss angedeutet werden, damit der Leser den Satz als Witz erkennt, statt diesen wörtlich zu verstehen. In moderner Internet-Sprache fügt man normalerweise ein Emoticon am Ende eines solchen Satzes hinzu (e.g. `^_^`, `:D`, `;)` und so weiter und so fort). Obwohl ich kein Problem damit habe, glaube ich, dass es sprachlich gesund ist, die gleiche Idee nur mit Worten darstellen zu können.

*Was schreibt man auf Deutsch, um so einen Witz anzudeuten?*

Comment: Nicht selten füge ich im Nachhinein wohl an, dass es nur ein Witz war. Auch auf English (Just kidding). Ansonsten kann man dazu keine allemeine Antwort geben. Es kommt immer auf den Kontext an. Und im 'echten Leben' bleibt dir ja auch nichts übrig, einen Satz als Witz erkennen zu lassen, indem man zum Beispiel mit lachender Stimme spricht, zwinkert oder sonst was.

Comment: Ja, genau, aber das Problem lautet, dass man schriftlich weder lächeln noch zwinkern kann. Ok, vielleicht jemand schreibt eine Liste, mit Redewendungen oder zu *ein Witz sein*-äquivalente Ausdrücke, sonst lass ich die Frage schlissen.

Comment: Eben das gibt es nicht.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wenn man einen echten **[Witz](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witz)** schreiben möchte, gibt es in der Regel keine Probleme, dies auch in der Schriftform eindeutig darzustellen (man könnte z. B. eine Einrückung vornehmen, oder einen anderen Font benutzen).

Ganz anders sieht es aus, wenn man scherzhafte oder ironische Textpassagen schreiben möchte. Hier sollten sich Schreiber und Empfänger der Nachricht gut kennen, damit die Ironie verstanden wird und keine Missverständnisse entstehen.

Ist das nicht der Fall, kann man natürlich die entsprechende Passage gesondert kennzeichnen, indem man sie in Anführungszeichen oder kursiv setzt. Ein gutes Mittel zur Kennzeichnung einer ironischen Passage ist, den Stil zu ändern. Man kann das Tempus oder die Person wechseln, oder umgangssprachliche Elemente einfügen. Man kann solche Passagen auch im Konjunktiv schreiben, um die Wahrhaftigkeit zu relativieren. Gerne kann auch eine völlige und damit eindeutige Übertreibung hier einem Missverständnis entgegenwirken.

Beispiele:

> - *Dein Auto ist ja eine wahre Rennmaschine. Bergab könnte ich damit einen Ferrari überholen.*
> - *Gestern habe ich ein "Luxusmenü" gekocht: Spagetti mit Tomatensoße.*

Answer (score 4):

Ein Witz ist ja eine kurze Geschichte mit einer überraschenden Pointe.

> Kommt eine Frau beim Arzt...

Schon von der Person und Zeit, mit der er erzählt wird, setzt er sich vom übrigen Text ab. Einen schnurgeraden Witz wird man im Zweifelsfall ausdrücklich als solchen kennzeichnen, ohne dass etwas von ihm verloren geht, wenn undeutlich bleiben könnte dass es ein solcher ist.

Als Einleitung verbreitet, v.a. mündlich, ist **Kennst Du den:**

> Ein Franzose, ein Ami und ein Deutscher sitzen im Flugzeug ...

Dazu im Gegensatz steht die Ironie. Ironie ist als subtiler Spott definiert und leidet darunter, wenn er mit Emoticons oder Anführungsstrichen das subtile aufgibt. Wenn man sich kennt, dann sind i.d.R. keine Markierungen nötig, weil der Empfänger der Nachricht den Sender genau genug kennt, um zu wissen was dieser ernst meint, und wo er stichelt.

Es kann aber auch interessant sein genau die Grenze zu finden, an denen es changiert und nicht so ganz klar ist, ob eine Bemerkung ernst gemeint ist oder ein feiner Spott. Ohne die Möglichkeit den Ausdruck falsch zu verstehen verliert dieser seinen Witz, weswegen die Emoticons auch eine derart lähmende Ödnis und Geistlosigkeit verbreiten.

Abschließend, der nahenden Wahl wegen, möchte ich anfügen, dass Frau Merkel die beste Bundeskanzlerin ist, die wir je hatten.

Comment: Aber Merkel ist doch die einzige Bundeskanzlerin, die wir je hatten.

Comment: Lieber @Takkat, wenn Du nicht verstehst, wieso ich das so schreibe wie ich es schreibe dann frag doch und versuch nicht dem Text Deine Intention aufzuzwingen. Bitte beachte die Regeln für das Überarbeiten von Texten, Schwerpunkt: sinnerhaltende Verbesserungen. Gerne können wir das auch auf Meta oder im Chat diskutieren.

Comment: Gute Antwort. Ironie braucht keine Hervorhebung, da sie eine Form der Ausdrucksweise ist, die darauf abzielt, versteckt zu sein und trotzdem verstanden zu werden. Dass das manchmal nicht funktioniert, liegt in der Natur der Sache; das zeigt dann höchstens, dass die Ironie schlecht gemacht war oder nicht vom Zielpublikum gelesen wurde.

Comment: Wenn der letzte Paragraph ein Beispiel für Ironie sein soll und nicht ein Teil der Antwort, ist es eine *"sinnnerhaltende"* Verbesserung, die Passage als solch ein Beispiel zu kennzeichnen.

Comment: Die Aussage der Antwort ist es ja gerade, dass Ironie nicht extra gekennzeichnet werden muss, daher auch das Beispiel, welches nicht gekennzeichnet wurde. Das Kennzeichnen  der Passage als Beispiel erhält dann nicht die Absicht des ursprünglichen Autors.

Comment: @blutorange: Danke, ich wusste, dass man es verstehen kann. :)

Comment: @Em1 Ach, wirklich?

Answer (score 3):

Ich finde das ist eine Lücke in unserer geschriebenen Sprache. Mündlich gibt es Gesten und Mimik, um Ironie zu untermalen. Schriftlich hingegen sieht das leider anders aus.

Ein Vorschlag aus dem 19. Jahrhundert ist auf [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironiezeichen) zu lesen:

> Das Ironiezeichen ist ein vorgeschlagenes, aber kaum verwendetes Satzzeichen, mit dem die ironische Bedeutung eines Satzes oder Satzteiles hervorgehoben werden kann. Es wird meist durch ein spiegelverkehrtes Fragezeichen (U+2E2E) dargestellt.

Die Idee finde ich persönlich super und man könnte sich für andere Stilmittel ähnliche Dinge einfallen lassen. Vielleicht wäre es dann endlich möglich, schriftlich zu diskutieren, ohne sich ständig falsch zu verstehen.

Man müsste eben nur eine gute Idee haben, die sich durchsetzen kann. Fangen wir damit an?

Aber insgesamt kann ich mich inhaltlich nur meinem "Vorschreiber" anschließen: Derzeit gibt es **keine einheitliche Regelung**. Man kann sich nur etwas einfallen lassen, was das Gegenüber vielleicht versteht. Vielleicht aber auch nicht.

Comment: Wäre eigentlich ne klasse Idee, aber ich glaube, nicht viele Zeichensätze haben dieses Zeichen. ⸮ wird bei mir als Köstchen, in dem "2E2E" drinsteht, angezeigt, und nicht als der gewünschte Glyph (spiegelbildliches Fragezeichen).

Comment: Gut, welches Zeichen man für welchen Inhalt nutzt kann man ja noch ändern. Außerdem, sollte sowas offiziell werden, steigt der Druck auf die Zeichensatz-Macher.. ä ö ü und ß gibt es ja auch nicht in allen Zeichensätzen.

Comment: Stimmt. Allerdings ist das ein Henne-Ei-Problem: wenn es uverständlich aussieht, nutzt es niemand; nutzt es niemand, wird es von den Font-Erstellern nicht implementiert. D. h. bei denen liegt wohl der schwarze Peter. Das [ẞ](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gro%C3%9Fes_%C3%9F) als Majuskelform des ß wird vermutlich auch erst langsam in die Zeichensätze aufgenommen werden...

Answer (score 2):

Ich meine, man kann ruhig eine Bemerkung hinzufügen etwa wie "Kleiner Scherz von mir" oder "Das ist natürlich nicht ernst gemeint".